# Nodemailer Ethereal emails are not deliver to the gmail

Tags: node.js, express, smtp, nodemailer, pop3

I'm trying to send emails using the following function using express js server. It seems to be working fine. But when I send email it’s not visible in my gmail inbox or spams.

Function i used:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: 'leo.skiles74@ethereal.email',
        pass: 'BJkKV41tNZNBmMkkCw'
    }
});

function SendEmail(email,subject,text,html) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let info = await transporter.sendMail({
                from: "leo.skiles74@ethereal.email",
                to: email,
                subject: subject,
                text: text,
                html:html
            })
            resolve(info)
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Response received:

```
{
  "accepted": [
    "gayantaanus@gmail.com"
  ],
  "rejected": [],
  "envelopeTime": 759,
  "messageTime": 506,
  "messageSize": 596,
  "response": "250 Accepted [STATUS=new MSGID=YpXX5N-8J14cOJVHYpXjvw93heVfMHMGAAAAA4okSTkzId5ci.tBPvM2244]",
  "envelope": {
    "from": "leo.skiles74@ethereal.email",
    "to": [
      "gayantaanus@gmail.com"
    ]
  },
  "messageId": "<91f5d48e-a363-b59a-d47b-c44736e49c43@ethereal.email>"
}
```

But not delivered to gmail. How to fix and explain to me the reason ?

Comment: I used sendinblue server It works fine.

Comment: https://www.sendinblue.com/free-smtp-server/ This is a link of sendinblue I used

Answer (score 1):

Ethereal is a **fake SMTP service**, mostly aimed at Nodemailer and EmailEngine users (but not limited to). It's a completely free anti-transactional email service where messages never get delivered.

Instead, you can generate a vanity email account right from Nodemailer, send an email using that account just as you would with any other SMTP provider and finally preview the sent message here as **no emails are actually delivered.**

just as stated in home page of ethereal, it does not actually deliver mail.
you can check on this link.
link: https://ethereal.email/

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
 if (err) {
console.error("Failed to create a testing account. " + err.message);
return process.exit(1);
}
console.log("Credentials obtained, sending message...");
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: account.smtp.host,
port: account.smtp.port,
secure: account.smtp.secure,
auth: {
  user: account.user,
  pass: account.pass,
},
});
 let message = {
from: "Sender Name <sender@example.com>",
to: "Recipient <recipient@example.com>",
subject: "Nodemailer is unicode friendly ✔",
text: "Hello to myself!",
html: "<p><b>Hello</b> to myself!</p>",
};
transporter.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error occurred. " + err.message);
  return process.exit(1);
}
console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
});
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have some issues with Ethereal too , but using a Gmail account work ok!.
Remember use a 2FA authentication, here is the doc:

https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

const TEST_EMAIL = "thegmailaccount@com"
const TEST_PASSWORD = "thegmailpwgenerated";
const CLIENT = "mailtodelivery@example.com";

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'gmail',
port: 587,
auth: {
    user: TEST_EMAIL,
    pass: TEST_PASSWORD,
}
});

const message = {
from: 'Dev <no-reply@exalple.com>',
to: `"Dear client!" ${CLIENT}`,
subject: "Hi Sir!",
text: "Text if the HTML dont load",
html: <h1 style="color: red; ">This is a example</h1>,
};

try {
const info = await transporter.sendMail(message);
console.log(info);
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure you can use it to deliver mails. It's kinda testnet stuff.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).